# Type Error : destroy is not a function in Reactjs while call api async function in useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

```
const [dailyData, setDailyData] = useState([]);
 useEffect(async () => {
    const fetchData =  await fetchDailyData();  // fetchDailyData() is calling Api 
    setDailyData(fetchData); 

    console.log(fetchData); //fetchData print the value but dailyData not updating


  },[]);
```

showing destroy is not a function and func.apply is not a function

Comment: _fetchData print the value but dailyData not updating_  `setDailyData` will update the state asynchronously, you can't log `dailyData` immediately after calling `setDailyData`

Comment: can you share fetchDailyData ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Effect hook callbacks ***can't*** be async. Instead, declare a callback function scoped async function and then invoke it. Also, as pointed out by @StéphaneVeyret your "async" effect hook callback implicitly returns a Promise which gets interpreted as an effect hook clean up function. It ***isn't*** one though and causes error.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const asyncFetchDailyData = async () => {
    const fetchData = await fetchDailyData(); // fetchDailyData() is calling Api 
    setDailyData(fetchData);
    console.log(fetchData);
  }

  asyncFetchDailyData();
}, []);
```

Comment: Just to add information: an asynchronous function will always return a result as a `Promise`. When calling `useEffect` react expects the function result, if any, to be a function which will be called to “clean” the effect. So the error.

Comment: Thank you! I had an async useEffect in next.js and the error message showed in an unrelated spot, you've saved me some hours.

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect(async () => {` //in this part the async is the wrong

instead of that you can create a function async inside of useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
  const asyncFetchDailyData = async () => {
  ...
  }

  asyncFetchDailyData();
}, []);
```